# FIDO U2F on a site with changing hostnames/IP addresses

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, two-factor-authentication, fido-u2f, yubico

I have a situation, where I want to implement FIDO U2F (using YubiKey) on an administrative interface to a load balancer, so that after login, in order to administer the system - U2F must be used as an extra layer of authentication.

Over the life span of the system - it’s common for the IP address and the hostname used to access it to change (e.g. once it’s https://192.168.0.20/, then it’s https://lb-admin.company.com/, then it’s something else, etc.).

The problem is that a key is being registered against an appId (the URL of the site) and then the appId is encoded in the keyHandle. Is there a way to allow multiple appIds or even remove the appId restriction when you register a key?

In other words - register one YubiKey and then use it from any entry point of the web site or even if the website is accessed using an IP address or a domain that is different from that, with which the key was initially registered?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can make a registered U2F key work with different hostnames buy using several subdomains... so it can be lb-admin.company.com and lb-login.company.com and whatever.company.com and so on. (Don't use IP)

In order to do so, your AppId reference should point to a online json file that will be processed as a TrustedFacetList.

Real world example... Here is the offcial GitHub AppID implementing this:
https://github.com/u2f/trusted_facets

All details and rules are described here:
FIDO AppID and Facet Specification (FacetID)
https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-u2f-v1.0-ps-20141009/fido-appid-and-facets-ps-20141009.html

Comment: the problem is that the already registered U2F key with the old App ID won't work with the new domain. So we have to request for registering the key with new App ID. Couldn't find any way to migrate the data.